# How to `lockForUpdate()` on an existing Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, locking, innodb

`lockForUpdate()` and `sharedLock()` are functions in Laravel Eloquent to set exclusive or shared locks (documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#pessimistic-locking)).

However, I couldnt find a nice syntax to apply this on a single, already instantiated Eloquent model. Consider the following example code:

```php
DB::transaction(function() {
    // Find the user with ID = 1.
    $user = User::find(1);
    $user->lockForUpdate()->update([
        'balance' => $user->balance + 1
    ]);

    // ... some more stuff happens here in the transaction
});
```

The code above will **NOT** work as expected. `lockForUpdate()` returns a new query builder here, and it will cause ALL users to have their balance incremented by one.

I want the `balance` property to be read-locked for the duration of this transaction, such that any other transaction that happens in parallel will not derail the account balance by calculating the wrong result. So how can I make sure that the `balance` property is locked while updating this user? I know I can call the following function but it seems a bit counter-intuitive to create a new query for this, which includes the `$user` variable as well:

```php
$updated = User::query()->where('id', 1)->lockForUpdate()->update([
    'balance' => $user->balance
]);
```

Note: I want to keep `->increment()` and `->decrement()` out of the equation here. I can't use these functions since I need Eloquent's `updating`/`updated`/`saving`/`saved` event hooks to fire properly (and they do not get triggered when using these functions). This is to be expected though, for more info see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18802#issuecomment-593031090 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hm it seems I managed to find a quick resolution to this question.

I think the intended way is to do this like so:

```php
DB::transaction(function() {
    // You can also use `findOrFail(1)` or any other query builder functions here depending on your needs.
    $user = User::lockForUpdate()->find(1);
    $user->update([
        'balance' => $user->balance + 1
    ]);
});
```

This will then generate the following SQL (excerpt from MySQL general query log):

```
200524 13:36:04    178 Query    START TRANSACTION
178 Prepare select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = ? limit 1 for update
178 Execute select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1 for update
178 Close stmt  
178 Prepare update `users` set `balance` = ?, `users`.`updated_at` = ? where `id` = ?
178 Execute update `users` set `balance` = 15, `users`.`updated_at` = '2020-05-24 13:36:04' where `id` = 1
178 Close stmt
QUERY     COMMIT
```

Comment: If you have multiple connections and query this on a none default connection, you have to mention the connection name `DB::connection('name')->transaction()`